# Canvas eyeDropper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I need to implement an eyedropper tool. I want it so you click the eyedropper button to make it active, then using a onmove it will change the colour of my colour picker and when you click using onclick it will set the colour to the colour picker using:

```
$('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPickerSetColor(eyeDropperColour);
```

The variable eyeDropperColour would be set using the onlick based on what colour pixel you are over.  I am wondering would I have to do it based on what layer as I have: canvas and canvasCursor.

I have been looking at this guide but I can't make it work for my project? http://palebluepixel.org/2011/11/16/html5-canvas-eyedropper/

Here is my project:
http://www.taffatech.com/Paint.html

I have:

```
var eyeDropperActive = false;
var eyeDropperColour;
```

and:

```
$("#brushEyeDropper").click(function() {

    if ( eyeDropperActive == true)
    {
      eyeDropperActive = false;
    }

    else if ( eyeDropperActive == false)
    {
     eyeDropperActive = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Creating a canvas “eyedropper” tool**

This is how to read the pixel color at any X/Y on the canvas:

```
    function getPixelColor(x, y) {
        var pxData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
        return("rgb("+pxData.data[0]+","+pxData.data[1]+","+pxData.data[2]+")");
    }
```

The rest is just controlling when to accept the color with a click on the canvas.

```
    var eyedropperIsActive=false; 

    // Activate reading pixel colors when a #startDropper button is clicked
    $("#startDropper").click(function(e){eyedropperIsActive=true;});

    // if the tool is active, report the color under the mouse
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

    // when the user clicks on the canvas, turn off the tool 
    // (the last color will remain selected)
    $("#canvas").click(function(e){eyedropperIsActive=false;});
```

And here is the mousemove event handler that calls getPixelColor and reports that color

```
    // if the tool is active, report any color under the mouse
    function handleMouseMove(e){

      if(!eyedropperIsActive){return;}

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      var eyedropColor=getPixelColor(mouseX,mouseY);
      $("#results").css("backgroundColor",getPixelColor(mouseX,mouseY));

    }
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/zpfdv/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:30px; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #results{width:30px; height:30px; border:1px solid blue;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var eyedropperIsActive=false;

    drawTestColors(20,20,"red");
    drawTestColors(100,20,"green");
    drawTestColors(180,20,"blue");

    function drawTestColors(x,y,color){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.rect(x,y,50,50);
        ctx.fill();
    }


    function getPixelColor(x, y) {
        var pxData = ctx.getImageData(x,y,1,1);
        return("rgb("+pxData.data[0]+","+pxData.data[1]+","+pxData.data[2]+")");
    }


    function handleMouseMove(e){

      if(!eyedropperIsActive){return;}

      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      var eyedropColor=getPixelColor(mouseX,mouseY);
      $("#results").css("backgroundColor",getPixelColor(mouseX,mouseY));

    }

    $("#canvas").click(function(e){eyedropperIsActive=false;});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#startDropper").click(function(e){eyedropperIsActive=true;});

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Click "Activate Eyedropper" to read pixel color under the mouse</p>
    <p>Click canvas to set the color and de-active the eyedropper</p>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
    <button id="startDropper">Activate Eyedropper</button>
    <div id="results" width=30 height=30>&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a new js API for eyedropper. it is more concise and will do the same job done with a lot less code.

```
if('EyeDropper' in window){
  const dropper = new window.EyeDropper()
  dropper.open().then((result) => {
    console.log(result.sRGBHex);
  })
}else{
  alert('Eye Dropper Not Supported in your Browser Current Version.\nPlease Update your Browser to use this feature')
}
```